# Get visible li:last and not hidden li:last

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to do something with li:last:

```
var p = $("li:last");
```

I need its position: `position.left`

With the position I can align some element. The problem is that in some cases the last li is 'hidden' by event.hide, so that means I get `position.left 0` Which means the element does not align since the value is 0.

How do I get li:last of all the visible li? (So the li which is hidden should not play along)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `$("li:visible:last")` -> used `:visible` selector.

Answer (score 1):

This is your solution:

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selectors

```
var p = $("li:visible:last");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var pos = $("li:last:visible").position();
console.log(pos.left);
```

Answer (score 1):

this should works

```
var p=$('li:visible').last();
//some stuff
```

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/